# Api Create user WEB_LOGIN_REQUIRED

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When I try to create a user using Api Admin SDK, this user is created but is suspended. The reason is WEB_LOGIN_REQUIRED. When the user try to enter in this account have to verify this account using phone sms. These users are students, so they dont have phone. ¿How do I create this account without having to verify?

To create this user account we use a service account. This is the code to create

```
    UsersResource.InsertRequest user = service.Users.Insert(new User
    {
        PrimaryEmail = usuarionuevo.Email,
        Name = new UserName
        {
            GivenName = usuarionuevo.NombreSimple,
            FamilyName = usuarionuevo.Apellidos,
            FullName = usuarionuevo.Nombre,
        },
        Suspended = false,
        Password = usuarionuevo.Password,
        ChangePasswordAtNextLogin = true
    });
```

[Validation Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH3v8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is true that a Web Login is required to confirm that the user exists and really wants to use his account
- However, the phone verification is optional
- When the users see the following screen:

[image]

they just need to press on **CONFIRM** to start using their account

- Phone verification is good for safety reasons but optional unless there is [suspicion for unauthorized access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6002699?hl=en)

UPDATE

A possible reason while your account might be considered as "suspicious" and require additional authentication is if you are a trial user.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the user always need enter a phone. the title is "
We have detected unusual activity on the account you are trying to access. To continue, follow the instructions below", but this is the first time that the user try to enter. Could it be that I am missing some important information in the new user, or that the password that I think is not correct? 
I include a validation request image in the original question

Comment: Did this happen only for 1 user or several? Does it happen only if you create the user programmatically or also ROM teh UI user interface? Did the user ever log in successfully? You can either prechose a password for the user or autogenerate it and you can chose either the user is supposed to change it after logging in for the first time.

Comment: I've seen that always happen. Even when I use UI (console administrator). I tried with the automatic generation password (and not) and the user always has to verify the account with sms. Could it be some Gsuite setup? I have not seen anywhere to remove that is required to verify by mobile.

Comment: Can you go in your Admin console to `Security` and `Login challenges` and make sure that you have enabled `Logins using SSO bypass additional verifications`?

Comment: Yes,  i have enabled this option "Logins using SSO bypass additional verifications". 
I am testing it in the Gsuit trial version. Could this be the reason?